# Hibernate. Варианты реализации One-to-many по аналогии с union select

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Добрый день.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой набор таблиц. Стандартно с помощью SQL выбрать все "сервисы" со всеми их специфическим атрибутами можно с помощью select union, (упрощенно)

```
  SELECT common_attr1 as AA, common_attr2 as BB, specific_attr2 CC FROM Service INNER JOIN Specific_service1 ON id_Service WHERE ID_ = ...
  UNION 
  SELECT common_attr1 as AA, specific_attr4 as BB, specific_attr5 CC FROM Service INNER JOIN Specific_service2 ON id_Service WHERE ID_ = ...
  UNION
  SELECT ...
```

Как с помощью native SQL добавлять/изменять данные, то же понятно.

Но в проекте ативно используется Hibernate
Напрямую Union в Hibernate нет.

Соответственно вопрос:
Как с помощью Hibernate оформить Entity, способные реализовать такие выборки?
Какие варианты есть? Может быть предварительно сделать View в БД?
Может быть есть полезные ссылки с описание решения подобных задач?
Сам пока информации не нашел.

Comment: Если честно, я в таких ситуациях шел по простому пути и создавал вьюшку. После просто создавал для нее 'Entity' как для таблицы.